# A doubt about the definition of absolute continuity on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

We say tha a collection of closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ is non-overlapping if their interiors are disjoint. A real- valued function $f$ on a finite closed interval $[a,b]$ is said to ve absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any finite collection of non-overlapping closed intervals $\{[a_k,b_k]\:\; k=1,\dots, n\}$ contained in $[a,b]$ with $\sum_{k=1}^n(b_k-a_k)<\delta$, we have $\sum_{k=1}^n |f(b_k)-f(a_k)|<\varepsilon$

> Is the definition of absolute continuity in $\mathbb{R}$ exactly the one just written where instead of $[a,b]$ I replace $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: That [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Definition) is for any interval $I \subset \Bbb R$, in particular for $I = \Bbb R$.